# Stop postback after reseting Jquery validation by javascript in ASP.NET Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback

I have one form inside that form there are two buttons and two text box and after clicking first button validation appears for first textbox field after clicking second button validation of first textbox disappears but with post back .

How can I prevent post back while reseting jquery validation.

```
      <form id="form1" runat="server">

                    <div id="div1" class="form-horizontal">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                                    <asp:TextBox  ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-md-3">

                                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1"  CssClass="submit btn btn-primary " runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                            <div id="div2" class="form-horizontal">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-md-3">

                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                     </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                </form>




<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button1').click(function () {
                $('#form1').validate({
                    errorClass: 'help-block animation-slideDown',
                    errorElement: 'div',
                    errorPlacement: function (error, e) {
                        e.parents('.form-group > div').append(error);
                    },
                    highlight: function (e) {
                        $(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error').addClass('has-error');
                        $(e).closest('.help-block').remove();
                    },
                    success: function (e) {
                        e.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error');
                        e.closest('.help-block').remove();
                    }, 
                         rules: {
                             'TextBox1': {
                                required: true,
                            },
                        },
                        messages: {
                            'TextBox1': {
                                required: 'ProvideYourCurrentPassword',
                            },
                        },
                });
                $("#TextBox2").rules('remove');
            });
            $('#Button2').click(function () {
                $('#form1').validate({
                    errorClass: 'help-block animation-slideDown',
                    errorElement: 'div',
                    errorPlacement: function (error, e) {
                        e.parents('.form-group > div').append(error);
                    },
                    highlight: function (e) {
                        $(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error').addClass('has-error');
                        $(e).closest('.help-block').remove();
                    },
                    success: function (e) {
                        e.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error');
                        e.closest('.help-block').remove();
                    },

                    rules: {
                             'TextBox2': {
                                required: true,
                            },
                        },
                        messages: {
                            'TextBox2': {
                                required: 'ProvideYourCurrentPassword',
                            },
                        },
                });
                $("#TextBox1").rules('remove');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: write `e.preventDefault()` for each `button` and once `formvalidation` is done based on `valid` or not just `submit` the form or keep it as it is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script, it may help you.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#form1').validate({
                errorClass: 'help-block animation-slideDown',
                errorElement: 'div',
                errorPlacement: function (error, e) {
                    e.parents('.form-group > div').append(error);

                },
                highlight: function (e) {
                    $(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error').addClass('has-error');
                    $(e).closest('.help-block').remove();
                },
                success: function (e) {
                    e.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success has-error');
                    e.closest('.help-block').remove();
                },
            });
            $('#Button1').click(function () {
                $("#TextBox1").rules("add", { required: true, messages: { required: '<%=ValidationMessage.ProvideYourCurrentPassword%>' } });
                $("#TextBox2").each(function () {
                    $(this).rules('remove');
                });
            });


            $('#Button2').click(function () {
                $("#TextBox2").each(function () {
                    $(this).rules('add', {
                        required: true
                    });
                });
                $("#TextBox1").each(function () {
                    $(this).rules('remove');
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Post your Jquery Code inside the `Sys.Application.add_load`

```
$(function(){
            Sys.Application.add_load(function () { 
           // your Java script Code here
                   });

            });
```

Comment: after putting my jquery code inside Sys.Application.add_load jquery validation stopped working  but thanks for reply